# Join instead of subquery

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table like the following one:

```
 id   user_id    task    task_closed 
  1       1       1         0
  2       1       2         1
  3       1       3         0
  4       2       3         0 
  5       2       4         1
  6       3       4         0
```

What I need is a query that for a given task will return all the uses that have this task and for each of them the number of overall un-closed tasks they have.

so that if we are talking about task 3
I want to get

```
user_id  pending
   1        2
   2        1
```

as in

```
SELECT tasks.user_id,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM tasks t2 
         WHERE t2.user_id=tasks.user_id AND t2.task_closed=0
       )
FROM tasks
WHERE tasks.id=?
```

I would also re-write this as

```
  SELECT user_id,COUNT(*) 
  FROM tasks  
  WHERE task=? AND task_closed=0 
  GROUP_BY user_id
  WHERE user_id IN (SELECT t2.user_id from tasks t2 WHERE task=?);
```

But I have a strong feeling that there should be a more efficient way to do this by somehow joining the table with itself.

any ideas on how I should do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.user_id,
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    tasks t1
INNER JOIN tasks t2
    ON t2.user_id=t1.user_id 
    AND t2.task_closed=0
WHERE 
    t1.id=?
```

But assuming that the id of the task is `task` column and not `id` column (since id is unique and that means that for 1 task you have no more the one user)

```
SELECT 
    t1.user_id,
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    tasks t1
INNER JOIN tasks t2
    ON t2.user_id=t1.user_id 
    AND t2.task_closed=0
WHERE 
    t1.task=?
GROUP BY
    t1.user_id
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to join the results of the query from above to get additional info ex: some user details (`field` column from `user_details` table) you can use:

```
SELECT
    tmp.user_id,
    tmp.nb,
    user_details.field
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t1.user_id,
        COUNT(*) as nb
    FROM 
        tasks t1
    INNER JOIN tasks t2
        ON t2.user_id=t1.user_id 
        AND t2.task_closed=0
    WHERE 
        t1.task=?
    GROUP BY
        t1.user_id
) as tmp
LEFT JOIN user_details
    ON user_details.user_id = tmp.user_id
```

Comment: task is indeed the column that hlods task id's.

Comment: Yes and its working. but somehow I am still missing the point of how to do what I want in a general case :( for example - suppose I now want to join the results of this query with some other table (e.g. to get some data based on user_id that might occur in multiples - like foods liked by the user - and I will expect to get multiple rows with the data from the current results duplicated per each liked food).  I will accept your answer here but if you ca provide more insight I would be greatful.

Comment: i've updated my answer pls check and let me know if its what you needed

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
   b.userid,
   count(*) as cnt
FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT userId FROM tasks WHERE task=?) a
INNER JOIN 
   tasks b
ON
   a.userId=b.userid
WHERE 
   b.task_closed = 0
GROUP BY 
   b.userid
```

This will replicate what your does. But I am confused about your query. you are counting task-closed for all tasks but you want result for only task as given by the user.

Comment: I am tring to look at the users related to a specific task but want to know how many open tasks each of them has.

Comment: EXPLAIN on this SQL code seems to be less efficient then others.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work:

select tasks.user_id,count(*) from tasks where tasks.task=? and task_closed=0 group by user_id

Comment: IHMO this only looks at the task status for the specific task for each user and not at all the tasks for those users.
i.e. in my example if asked about task 3 if will only return info based on rows 3 & 4 of the table and ignore other rows that belong to the users in those rows.